# The two 5-cycle conjugacy classes of $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I had a homework problem in my abstract algebra class that had us compute the elements of the two 5-cycle conjugacy classes in $A_5$. I found a lot of examples where the order of the class was computed, but no problems regarding the members. It was in the unit on Group Actions, so I'm assuming there's an elegant way of doing this using that concept, but I ended up brute forcing it.

Is there a much better way to solve this problem? Can it be extended to compute the members of conjugacy classes on $S_n$ or the members of other groups' conjugacy classes?

EDIT: Given some element $h$ in such a conjugacy class in $A_5$, is there a way of computing the other elements of the conjugacy class aside from computing $ghg^{-1}$ for all $g\in A_5$?

Comment: Note that conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are much easier to compute.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are entirely determined by the cycle type.

Applying conjugation by the permutation $\sigma$ to an element of form $(1,2,3)(4,5) \dots$ acts as if the permutation $\sigma$ is applied to the underlying set $\{1,2,3,4,5 \dots\}$ to give $(1\sigma, 2\sigma, 3\sigma)(4\sigma, 5\sigma) \dots$ - the only technicality being whether permutations are written on the right or on the left. You should prove this result, which you will need.

In $A_n$ you can't realise the odd permutations of the underlying set, but if a permutation has two cycles of the same odd length - two fixed elements or two $3$-cycles, for example - these can be exchanged by an odd permutation and all permutations of that cycle type can be realised through conjugation by an even permutation.

So for the $5$-cycles in $A_5$ elements of the two classes are related by conjugation by odd permutations.

Comment: Hm, so once I've found the members of one conjugacy class in $A_n$, I can get all the members of the other by multiplying them by an odd permutation?

Comment: @JoshC - by conjugating with odd permutations: note that only some conjugacy classes split.

Comment: A conjugacy class only splits in $A_n$ if its elements have either an even number of cycles or two cycles of the same length, correct?

Comment: @JoshC Not quite. The class of $5$-cycles does not split in $A_7$ because there are two fixed points. The class containing $(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8)$ splits in $A_8$ - the cycles have even length, and the permutations exchanging them are even.